# Set custom basic shortcut in a Bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently trying to optimize or learn the keybindings of the applications I use the most, in a simple and ergonomic way. Inspired by [Ergoemacs](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html) keybindings, I would like to rebind some very basics commands for use in Bash as for example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> : up/down/left/right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>/<kbd>o</kbd> : backward/forward word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>/<kbd>f</kbd> : delete left/right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>/<kbd>r</kbd> : delete word left/right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>/<kbd>r</kbd> : delete to begining/end of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd> : copy/cut/paste
- etc

I've seen ways to bind custom complex commands. I've found nowhere how to do this. In windows I used to do it system wide with autohotkeys but I'm now with a linux system and no autohotkey alternative works well for me.

How can I set those key bindings for my Bash terminal?

Comment: As an example, here is how I setup the keys I use in bash: https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/init/shkeys/bashkeys.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bash key-bindings configuration

- For *all above combinations, except the last one* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>...

You are looking for `readline` ([documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html)) library settings. In Linux, programs that offer some kind of command line interface (e.g. bash interactive shell, octave interactive shell, python interactive shell etc.) use `readline` library to customize key-bindings.

Key-bindings are usually added in `.inputrc` configuration file in user's home directory. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Sample-Init-File.html) is an example of `.inputrc` configuration file.

### Terminal emulator (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) key-bindings configuration

- For *the last one* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>...

In menubar of terminal emulator: `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts`.

Comment: Everything is working fine for most bindings. But I still have problems trying to bind commands to C-i and C-m, that seems to be aliases for respictively TAB and RETURN. In my scheme, I want to use C-i as a substitute for the upper arrow, and C-m for sometting else; but when I press the real TAB and RETURN, commands binded to C-i and C-m are triggered. Any solution to this problem?